# How to find if a file pattern is in the S3_bucket location

Tags: python, sql, boto3

I need to compare the S3 folder if any of them contains the file name which has the similar content like config.file_pattern in snowflake table :

---

I have a table (Config table) in snowflake where it stores a column called **file_pattern** which has the values like ".***file_name_pattern***.csv". (It is like a while card in SQL before and after the * it can have any value ) . It has other file formats as well like .txt ,.xls , so I mean to say that CSV is not a constant value.
I need to compare this **file_pattern** with S3 bucket file list and see if the folder has anything which matches the **file_pattern**

Select file_pattern from Config ;

| **file_pattern** |
| --- |
| .*file_name_pattern1*.csv |
| .*file_name_pattern2*.txt |
| .*file_name_pattern3*.png |

---

below is the sample S3 folder structure

DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/DIR4/**file_name_pattern1**_20190904.CSV

---

###Question :###

how do I compare this Wildcard field in snowflake column  **file_pattern** to S3 folder .
The tricky part is , I should also consider the .csv while comparing , not just the **file_pattern**.

I tried splitting the record from * to * in " *file_name_pattern*.csv" , again this will not consider .csv at the end

File_Pattern = [.*file_name_pattern1*.csv , .*file_name_pattern2*.pgp, *File_name_pattern.*.txt]

item['Key'] = DIR1/DIR2/DIR3/DIR4/file_name_pattern_20190904.CSV   (This is the result of s3 folder/file list. this i got it through connecting to S3 by boto3)

Below is the initial version I tried which obviously did not work as it was comparing one to one match

```
for file in File_Pattern :

    if file in item['Key']:

        "Run a query"
```

Try 2 :

```
for file in File_Pattern :

    file_1 = file.split('*') #(result was like [.,file_name_pattern1,.csv]

    if file_1[1] in item['Key']:

        "Run a query"
```

In this I was missing .csv if I compare just file_1[1]

I am not sure how to handle this

Comment: Can you try to re-word and clarify your question. Maybe provide better examples so it is easier to understand?

Comment: I edited to make it understand better.

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the exact problem but it does sound like existence of '*' in the file pattern is tripping you.

I think you are on the right path. It might work to ignore '*' as `in` operator will look for that segment between the '*'s anyway and focus on the end of the file (i.e. file type, .csv, .txt).

Taking your your second try, you might for example tweak it a bit to add the second condition to account for extension:

```
file_1 = file.split('*') #(result was like [.,file_name_pattern1,.csv]
if file_1[1] in item['Key'] and file_1[-1] == item['Key'][-4:]:
```

here you are asking both pattern and extension to match.
`file_1[-1]` would be the '.csv', '.txt' etc. ie., the extension part which would be the last element of the split result.
`item['Key'][-4:]` would give you the last 4 letters.